# How can I share variable data across different files in React

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to set up graphs in my stockmarket project. I am trying to display the graph of the stock clicked on in Gatsby.

Currently, I can display the stock graph of any stock by manually typing in the stock name to the code. I would like to replace the stock name with ${query} inside of the url of the api call because of `const query = event.target.value` in `index.js`. So the searched term will be saved as query and I need to have access to the same variable in my other file `chartData.js` so that I can change my API call from `` let API_CALL = `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/chart/5y?token=${API_KEY}`; ``  into `` let API_CALL = `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${query}/chart/5y?token=${API_KEY}`; `` Thus I will have access to whichever term is searched and be able to turn it into a graph.

I thought maybe I could use state to do this, like moving query to state via `query: this.state.value` or `query: {this.state.value}`. Both of these returned errors so I figured that would not work (or I was doing it wrong at least).

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from "axios"
import "../css/style.css"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { symbol } from "prop-types"

export default class index extends React.Component {
  state = {
      companyName: "",
      previousClose: "",
      marketCap: "",
      change: "",
      symbol: "",
      topStocks: [],
      Yearweekhigh: "",
      Yearweeklow: "",
      avgTotalVolume: "",
      peRatio: "",
      

  }
     
  

  clickHandler = (event) => {
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          const query = event.target.value;
          const API_KEY = '******************';
      axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${query}/quote?token=${API_KEY}`)
          .then(res => {
              const companyName = res.data['companyName'];
              this.setState({ companyName })

              const previousClose = res.data['previousClose'];
              this.setState({ previousClose })

              const marketCap = res.data['marketCap'];
              this.setState({ marketCap })

              const change = res.data['change'];
              this.setState({ change })

              const symbol = res.data['symbol'];
              this.setState({ symbol })

              const Yearweekhigh = res.data['week52High'];
              this.setState({ Yearweekhigh })

              const Yearweeklow = res.data['week52Low'];
              this.setState({ Yearweeklow })

              const avgTotalVolume = res.data['avgTotalVolume'];
              this.setState({ avgTotalVolume })

              const peRatio = res.data['peRatio'];
              this.setState({ peRatio }) 


          })
      }
  }



  render() {
      return (
          <Layout>
              <div class = "main-div">
                  <input type="search" class="main-search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)}/>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Ticker-Symbol</th>
                      <th>Market Cap</th>
                      <th>Previous Close</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Link to='/details/' state={{

                        setState: this.state.symbol, 
                        companyName: this.state.companyName, 
                        previousClose: this.state.previousClose,
                        marketCap: this.state.marketCap,
                        change: this.state.change,
                        Yearweekhigh: this.state.Yearweekhigh,
                        Yearweeklow: this.state.Yearweeklow,
                        avgTotalVolume: this.state.avgTotalVolume,
                        peRatio: this.state.peRatio

                        }}>
                          {this.state.symbol}</Link>


                        </td>
                      <td>{this.state.marketCap}</td>
                      <td>{this.state.previousClose}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div>
                {
                  this.state.topStocks.length && this.state.topStocks.map(stock => (
                  <h1>{stock.symbol}</h1>
                  ))
                }
              </div>
          </Layout>
      )
  }
}
```

chartData.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js'

class Stock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stockChartXValues: [],
            stockChartYValues: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchStock();
    }

    fetchStock() {
        const pointerToThis = this;
        const API_KEY = '**************************';
        let API_CALL = `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/chart/5y?token=${API_KEY}`;
        let stockChartXValuesFunction = [];
        let stockChartYValuesFunction = [];

        fetch(API_CALL)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {

            for (var x in data) {
                stockChartXValuesFunction.push(x);
                stockChartYValuesFunction.push(
                    data[x]['uOpen']
                );

                pointerToThis.setState({
                    stockChartXValues: stockChartXValuesFunction,
                    stockChartYValues: stockChartYValuesFunction,
                });
            }


        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Plot
                data={[
                    {
                        x: this.state.stockChartXValues,
                        y: this.state.stockChartYValues,
                        type: "scatter",
                        mode: "lines+markers",
                        marker: {color: "red"}
                    },
                ]}
                layout={{ width: 720, height: 440, title: "A Fancy Plot"}}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Stock
```

Comment: Just watched a video on it. Do not know a whole lot about it. Will it solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React if you need to share data between components the best approach is to use `state` and `props` to communicate the data.  In this case your best bet is probably to store whatever variables you need to share as state in your parent or root component, then you can pass both the state data and setter functions to other components in your app through properties.

For example:

```
    function Welcome(props) {
      return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
    }

    function Bye(props) {
      return <h1>Bye, {props.name}</h1>;
    }

    function App() {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
              name: '',
          };
        }
      return (
        <div>
          <Welcome name="Sara" />
          <Welcome name="Cahal" />
          <Bye name="Edite" />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

This is the official approach recommend in the official React docs, see section [The Data Flows Down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down) section.

Comment: When I try to add query to state at the end like ```query = event.target.value``` and then access it in the backtics like ```${this.state.query}``` I get ``` ERROR #98123  WEBPACK```

Comment: You need to add it the same way you add your other state variables, using `:` not `=`.  For instance to create an empty string state variable `query: ""`.  Then later in your code you access its value directly or call `setState({query: ""new_value"})` to update it

Comment: Oh yes, my bad that was a typo. Adding it as ```query: event.target.value``` and ```query: {event.target.value}``` both return the same error as previous. And adding it as ```query: "event.target.value" ``` does not keep the same functionality as it is now a string and it does not access the input bars input information.