# Sending 'sent' data from a page to a component in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have state data in my index.js page that is being sent to my details.js page via the Link component built into gatsby. From my details.js page, I am trying to send data to my component ChartData.js.

In details.js I can access my information by using `{props.location.state.x}`. Now I need the same data to be sent to my component and what I did was put Stock (Stock is the class name in ChartData.js) the comonent and set 'symbol' equal to the way I would reference data just like this: `{<Stock symbol={props.location.state.symbol}/>}`

Now under ChartData/.js when I try to reference symbol I get the error 'symbol is not defined'. Not sure if I am messing up the syntax of passing it or if you cannot do it this way.

index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from "axios"
import "../css/style.css"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { symbol } from "prop-types"
//import Stock from "../components/ChartData"
//import Characters from "../components/ChartData"

export default class index extends React.Component {
  state = {
      companyName: "",
      previousClose: "",
      marketCap: "",
      change: "",
      symbol: "",
      topStocks: [],
      Yearweekhigh: "",
      Yearweeklow: "",
      avgTotalVolume: "",
      peRatio: "",
      

  }    
  

  clickHandler = (event) => {
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          const query = event.target.value;
          const API_KEY = '******************';
      axios.get(`https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${query}/quote?token=${API_KEY}`)
          .then(res => {
              const companyName = res.data['companyName'];
              this.setState({ companyName })

              const previousClose = res.data['previousClose'];
              this.setState({ previousClose })

              const marketCap = res.data['marketCap'];
              this.setState({ marketCap })

              const change = res.data['change'];
              this.setState({ change })

              const symbol = res.data['symbol'];
              this.setState({ symbol })

              const Yearweekhigh = res.data['week52High'];
              this.setState({ Yearweekhigh })

              const Yearweeklow = res.data['week52Low'];
              this.setState({ Yearweeklow })

              const avgTotalVolume = res.data['avgTotalVolume'];
              this.setState({ avgTotalVolume })

              const peRatio = res.data['peRatio'];
              this.setState({ peRatio }) 

              const open = res.data['open'];
              this.setState({ open })

              const high = res.data['high'];
              this.setState({ high })

              const low = res.data['low'];
              this.setState({ low })

              const volume = res.data['volume'];
              this.setState({ volume })


          })
      }
  }



  render() {
      return (
          <Layout>
              <div class = "main-div">
                  <input type="search" class="main-search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)}/>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Ticker-Symbol</th>
                      <th>Market Cap</th>
                      <th>Previous Close</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Link to='/details/' state={{

                        setState: this.state.symbol, 
                        companyName: this.state.companyName, 
                        previousClose: this.state.previousClose,
                        marketCap: this.state.marketCap,
                        change: this.state.change,
                        Yearweekhigh: this.state.Yearweekhigh,
                        Yearweeklow: this.state.Yearweeklow,
                        avgTotalVolume: this.state.avgTotalVolume,
                        peRatio: this.state.peRatio,
                        open: this.state.open,
                        high: this.state.high,
                        low: this.state.low,
                        volume: this.state.volume,
                        symbol: this.state.symbol

                        }}>
                          {this.state.symbol}</Link>


                        </td>
                      <td>{this.state.marketCap}</td>
                      <td>{this.state.previousClose}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div>
                {
                  this.state.topStocks.length && this.state.topStocks.map(stock => (
                  <h1>{stock.symbol}</h1>
                  ))
                }
              </div>
          </Layout>
      )
  }
}
```

details.js

```
//import { Link } from "gatsby"
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import "../css/style.css"
import Stock from "../components/ChartData"

const Details = props => {
  const [yourState, setYourState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {

  }, []);

  return  <Layout>
    <div>
    <h1 class="details-company-name">{props.location.state.companyName}</h1>
    <div class = "details-div">
      <div class="details-div-1">
        <p>Open <h2>{props.location.state.open}</h2> </p>
        <p>High <h2>{props.location.state.high}</h2> </p>
        <p>Low <h2>{props.location.state.low}</h2> </p>
        <p>52 WK HIGH <h2>{props.location.state.Yearweekhigh}</h2> </p>
        <p>52 WK LOW <h2>{props.location.state.Yearweeklow}</h2> </p>
        <p>{props.location.state.symbol}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="details-div-2">
        <p>VOLUME <h2>{props.location.state.volume}</h2></p>
        <p>AVG VOL <h2>{props.location.state.avgTotalVolume}</h2> </p>
        <p>MKT CAP <h2>{props.location.state.marketCap}</h2></p>
        <p>P/E RATIO <h2>{props.location.state.peRatio}</h2></p>
        <p>DIV/YIELD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <Stock symbol={props.location.state.symbol}/>
      </Layout>;
    };

export default Details;
```

ChartData.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js'

class Stock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stockChartXValues: [],
            stockChartYValues: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchStock();
    }

    fetchStock() {
        const pointerToThis = this;
        const API_KEY = '*****************';
        let API_CALL = `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/${symbol}/aapl/chart/5y?token=${API_KEY}`;
        let stockChartXValuesFunction = [];
        let stockChartYValuesFunction = [];

        fetch(API_CALL)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {

            for (var x in data) {
                stockChartXValuesFunction.push(x);
                stockChartYValuesFunction.push(
                    data[x]['uOpen']
                );

                pointerToThis.setState({
                    stockChartXValues: stockChartXValuesFunction,
                    stockChartYValues: stockChartYValuesFunction,
                });
            }


        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Plot
                data={[
                    {
                        x: this.state.stockChartXValues,
                        y: this.state.stockChartYValues,
                        type: "scatter",
                        mode: "lines+markers",
                        marker: {color: "red"}
                    },
                ]}
                layout={{ width: 720, height: 440, title: "A Fancy Plot"}}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Stock
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I share variable data across different files in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005503/how-can-i-share-variable-data-across-different-files-in-react)

Comment: Not quite as when I try to pass symbol into ChartData.js it still says it is undefined. I have tried passing it from index.js to ChartData.js at the end of the index.js file like ```<Stock symbol="ba"/>``` and like ```<Stock symbol={this.state.symbol}/>``` and neither of which let symbol be defined in ChartData.js when I use it like ```https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${symbol}/chart/5y?token=${API_KEY}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues there:

- Everything you pass through `props` must be received by the child component accessing to those `props`. So instead of `symbol`, you must `this.props.symbol`. Since you are not destructuring your `props`:

  ```
  let API_CALL = 
  `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/${this.props.symbol}/aapl/chart/5ytoken=${API_KEY}`;
  ```
- To avoid wrong or empty calls, I would ensure that you have your `props` properly set and I would add a condition like:

  ```
   componentDidMount() {
    if(props.symbol) this.fetchStock();
   }
  ```
- You may need to add a constructor in your file to gather `props`:

  ```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {}; // remove if not needed
  }
  ```

Comment: I accepted the answer as it looks correct but now when I implement it it is saying 'props is not defined'

Comment: You are missing the `constructor(props)` and `super(props)` as you have in `ChartData.js`

Comment: I just switched it to ```{this.props.symbol}``` instead ```{props.symbol}``` in both the API call and the componentDidMount() and it is working perfect now, thank you!